# How to create n-1 dummy coding features based off categorical column in R

Tags: r, data-science

data_frame name: Bank_data has multiple categorical columns, for example:
Marital_Status: Married, Single, Divorced
Education: Uneducated, Primary, Secondary, Higher, Masters, Doctor 
Employment_Status: Unknown, Employed, Unemployed, Self-employed

for c("Marital_Status","Education","Employment_Status") I wanted R to automatically create a dummy column for each of the variables in the 3 columns from the list keeping n-1 columns to avoid multicollinearity issues. It should look something like this:
Martital_Status_Married | Martital_Status_Single | Education_Uneducated

Answer (score 0):

read the help for `model.matrix()` (`?model.matrix()`)

```
bank_data <- expand.grid(Marital_Status = c("Married", "Single", "Divorced"),
                            Education = c("Uneducated", "Primary", "Secondary", "Higher", "Masters", "Doctor"),
                            Employment_Status = c("Unknown", "Employed", "Unemployed", "Self-employed"))
    bank_data                        
    one_hot <- model.matrix(~ ., bank_data)


> head(one_hot)
  (Intercept) Marital_StatusSingle Marital_StatusDivorced EducationPrimary EducationSecondary EducationHigher EducationMasters
1           1                    0                      0                0                  0               0                0
2           1                    1                      0                0                  0               0                0
3           1                    0                      1                0                  0               0                0
4           1                    0                      0                1                  0               0                0
5           1                    1                      0                1                  0               0                0
6           1                    0                      1                1                  0               0                0
  EducationDoctor Employment_StatusEmployed Employment_StatusUnemployed Employment_StatusSelf-employed
1               0                         0                           0                              0
2               0                         0                           0                              0
3               0                         0                           0                              0
4               0                         0                           0                              0
5               0                         0                           0                              0
6               0                         0                           0                              0
```